# What is the JQuery equivalent of YUI buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, templates, yui

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/button

More specifically, I want radio buttons. that can be checked/unchecked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/